# Issue with on change Jquery event While previewing Picture in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I have an issue with Previewing an image in IE. I have 2 HTML controls on my form. file upload button which is hidden and a normal which the user clicks to upload an image to preview. The code works perfectly in chrome and other browsers. But it has an issue when adding an image in IE. The first time when i upload the file it works but the next time when i upload the same or different image the change event is working. It seems like the change event is not working the first time. Could some one please help with this issue? Below is my code. Thanks in advance

***HTML***

```
 <div class="upldImg">
            <img id="imgfakebrowse" ng-click='imageUpload()' src="../Images/upload.png" style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" />
            <input type="file" id="imgfilebrowse" name="imgfilebrowse" style="display: none">
        </div>
```

***Javascript***

```
//Profile Image Upload 
    $scope.imageUpload = function () {
        //intitalize the file input tag to Null to clear previous uploads
        document.getElementById('imgfilebrowse').value = null;

        $("#imgfilebrowse").trigger('click');


        $("#imgfilebrowse").change(function () {
            $scope.uploadtrigger(this);
        });
    }



    //function readURL(e) {
    $scope.uploadtrigger = function (input) {
        //var file = e.target.files[0];
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imgUploaded').attr('src', e.target.result);

                var CandidateDetails = $scope.contactById;
                if ($("#imgfilebrowse")[0].files[0] != null && $("#imgfilebrowse")[0].files[0] != '') {
                    image = $("#imgfilebrowse")[0].files[0];
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("imgUploaded").src = $scope.contactById.ProfileImage.Url;
                }
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-src` directive.

```
<div class="upldImg">
    <img id="imgfakebrowse" ng-click='imageUpload()' ng-src="{{imgUrl}}"
         style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%;" />
</div>
```

JS

```
$scope.imgUrl = "../Images/upload.png"

$scope.imageUpload = function () {
    $scope.imgUrl = $scope.contactById.ProfileImage.Url;
}
```

It is better integrated with the AngularJS framework and has better cross-browser support.

For more information, see [AngularJS `ng-src` Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).